# Stdout / stderr redirection doesn't work at preventing /dev/tcp/host/port redirection errors

Tags: io-redirection, stdout, stderr

This is normal redirection.

```
user@linux:~$ randomcommand
randomcommand: command not found
user@linux:~$
```

**2>**

```
user@linux:~$ randomcommand 2> /dev/null
user@linux:~$
```

**&>**

```
user@linux:~$ randomcommand &> /dev/null
user@linux:~$
```

However, it doesn't work when I tried to do the same with different command as shown below.

**&>**

```
user@linux:~$ > /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/22 &> /dev/null && echo open || echo closed
bash: connect: Connection refused
bash: /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/22: Connection refused
closed
user@linux:~$
```

**2>**

```
user@linux:~$ > /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/22 2> /dev/null && echo open || echo closed
bash: connect: Connection refused
bash: /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/22: Connection refused
closed
user@linux:~$
```

What's wrong with these syntax and how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is output at the time `bash` is processing the `> /dev/tcp/localhost/22` redirection, and at that point stderr hasn't been redirected yet. Just change the order of those two redirections:

```
if 2> /dev/null > /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/22; then
  echo open
else
  echo closed
fi
```

Note that those `/dev/tcp/host/port` are not real files. `bash` (or `ksh` where that feature comes from) detects the fact that you're trying to redirect to those special files (you'll notice that if you change it to `/dev/./tcp` or `/dev//tcp` it no longer works) and instead of opening those files, creates a TCP socket and attempts to `connect()` it on the host and port. And it's when that `connect` fails that `bash` is reporting an error.

`zsh` has a `ztcp` builtin command instead (in the `zsh/net/tcp` module) which makes it a bit more intuitive and also allows more things like server side connections.